# Missing dependency when using DynamicParameters

Tags: c#, castle-windsor, castle

Using Castle.Windsor 2.5.4.32 and Castle.Core 2.5.2.0.

I've got a component that needs a string[] in its ctor.  The string[]
comes from a "settings" class.  I don't want the component dependent
on the settings class since it just needs the string[].  So I used
DynamicProperties to pull the data from the settings class, which was pulled from the container.  At least,
that's what I thought would happen.  Windsor is not able to resolve my
component as it says there's a missing dependency (the string[]).

Here's a quick (MSTest) test case.  This is the first time I've used
DynamicParameters so I might be doing something wrong.  Any ideas?

```
namespace WindsorTests.DynamicParametersTest
{
       using Castle.MicroKernel.Registration;
       using Castle.Windsor;
       using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

       [TestClass]
       public class DPTest
       {
               [TestMethod]
               public void TestMethod1()
               {
                       var container = new WindsorContainer();
                       container.Register(
                               Component.For<ISettings>().ImplementedBy<Settings>(),
                               Component.For<Foo>().DynamicParameters((k, p) =>
                                                                       {
                                                  var settings = k.Resolve<ISettings>();
                                                  p["data"] = settings.MoreData;
                                                                       })
                               );

                       var bar = container.Resolve<Foo>();
               }
       }

       public interface ISettings
       {
               string[] MoreData { get; }
       }

       public class Settings : ISettings
       {
               public string[] MoreData
               {
                       get { return new[] {"A", "B", "C"}; }
               }
       }

       public class Foo
       {
               public Foo(string[] data)
               {
               }
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your usage is perfectly fine.

I just ran the test case on Windsor 3 and it's passing. So I suppose that might be a bug in 2.5.x

Comment: Actually, its not a bug in 2.5.x either.  The test above passes (oops!).  I had set a breakpoint on the "Resolve" line and noticed in the debugger that there was one potentially misconfigured component. However, the resolve *DOES* work and it uses the DynamicParameters to supply the missing dependency. I've got something else going on that I can't figure out.  I'll probably post it to the Castle-Users Google group and look for opinions/ideas as to what I'm doing wrong since I can't create a repo test case.